# Why did I get the enlightened badge after a huge delay here?

Tags: discussion, enlightened-badge

I just got an Enlightened badge for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16333951/1069068).

However, the answer has 13 upvotes and I only received one today. It was also accepted some time back.

Why did I get a badge so late, instead of the usual delay of a day or so?

Comment: As far as the acceptance, [the timeline says otherwise](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16333951/timeline). It was only accepted momentarily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [timeline for the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16333951/timeline), your answer was accepted just today.  To get the Enlightened Badge, you must answer first, have a net score of 10+, and be accepted.

It was accepted some time back, but only momentarily.  The script that assigns the [Enlightened Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened) runs approximately every <s>2 hours</s> 10 minutes and didn't pick it up the first time.

Comment: Ahh I see. That makes perfect sense

Comment: Every 2 hours? Where did that come from? When I get Enlightened badges on Meta, they usually only take 10 - 15 minutes to be awarded.

Comment: @animuson It's a guesstimate based on when I've seen Enlightened Badges timestamps on SO.  If you know differently, please enlighten us.

Comment: @rgettman http://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ2Sl.png

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Sorry, the image is blocked by WebSense at my workplace.

Comment: It's proving you wrong and @animuson right by showing the badge awarded in 10 minutes interval.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I stand corrected.

Comment: Cheers, enjoy your new badge! ;)